# Count a string & sum them in a new column in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, sum

I have a dataset with different types of observations across several "transects". Still pretty new to R, and struggling with the below issue...

I need to calculate the number of "nest" observations in each transect, but I am getting an error that makes me think maybe I am not using the correct function? In the end, I want to create a new column called "nest_number" which has the sum of the number of observations equal to nest.

The data is in this format:

| transect | observation |
| --- | --- |
| 1A | nest |
| 1A | *NA* |
| 1A | nest |
| 1A | vocalization |
| 1A | *NA* |
| 2A | nest |
| 2A | *NA* |
| ... | ... |

Here is how I need the output to look:

| transect | observation | nest_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | nest | 2 |
| 1A | *NA* | 2 |
| 1A | nest | 2 |
| 1A | vocalization | 2 |
| 1A | *NA* | 2 |
| 2A | nest | 1 |
| 2A | *NA* | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Here is the code I used

```
dfNew <- df %>%
  group_by(transect) %>%
  mutate(number_nests = colSums(observation == "nest", na.rm = TRUE))
```

The error I get is:

'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
The error occurred in group 1: transect = "1A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sum` and not `colSums` because `colSums` expect a `data.frame/matrix`, but here we are doing the `sum` on a logical vector (`observation == "nest"`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(transect) %>% 
  mutate(nest_number = sum(observation == "nest", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  transect observation  nest_number
  <chr>    <chr>              <int>
1 1A       nest                   2
2 1A       <NA>                   2
3 1A       nest                   2
4 1A       vocalization           2
5 1A       <NA>                   2
6 2A       nest                   1
7 2A       <NA>                   1
```